# onChange TextField move cursor to start in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I try to check input with `onChange` method in `TextField` but after replacing text with `TextEditingController` cursor move to start of `TextField`.

This problem occurs only on the `Android` platform.

**Code**

```
TextField(
controller: textEditController,
onChanged: (content) {
                    textEditController.text = checkNumber(content);
                  },)
```

**flutter version**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.2.2-pre.41, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale
    en-IR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set the selection using the `TextEditingController`

```
TextField(
controller: textEditController,
onChanged: (content) {
  textEditController..text = checkNumber(content)
                    ..selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);
  },
)
```

Comment: I think offset must be `offset: textEditController.text.length`. please update answer

Comment: Then you would set the cursor at the end. The question was about setting it at the start, wasn't it?

Comment: My problem is the automatic move cursor to start after the changed text. I probably could not give a good question. anyway, my problem solved. thank you :)

Comment: Thx, Günter Zöchbauer. I'm glad we have a simpler solution rather than trying all these workarounds in Flutter issues group https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11416

Comment: what is checkNumber function?

Comment: That's just some custom validation function.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted solution didn't work for me - as I was setting both **text** and **selection** I needed to instead set **value**.

The [TextEditingController class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) documentation states:

*The text or selection properties can be set from within a listener added to this controller. If both properties need to be changed then the controller's value should be set instead.*

The documentation also has a relevant example that includes the following:

```
void initState() {
  _controller.addListener(() {
    final text = _controller.text.toLowerCase();
    _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
      text: text,
      selection: TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

This forces the entered text to be lower case and keeps the cursor at the end of the input.

Comment: this worked for me using TextSelection.fromPosition as well. thx

Answer (score 8):

**If you want to move cursor dynamically with text **

```
setState(() {

    String text = "sometext";

    _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
             text: text,
             selection: TextSelection(
                       baseOffset: text.length,
                       extentOffset: text.length)
    );
});
```

Comment: Simple and efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (I store the textEditController in a variable):

```
TextField(
  controller: textEditController,
  onChanged: (content) {
     int cursorPos = textEditController.selection.base.offset;               
     textEditController.text = checkNumber(content);
     textEditController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: cursorPos));
    },)
```